# ExecuteAsync() thread deadlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, youtube, youtube-data-api

My wpf app hangs on the following line:

```
  var channelsListResponse =  await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

The code, taken from the YouTube api v3 reference sample code, runs fine in a console app but not in wpf. How can I resolve this deadlock in wpf?
I tried changing it to channelsListRequest.Execute(), but still same problem.

```
 private async Task Run()
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for read-only access to the authenticated 
                // user's account, but not other types of account access.
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
            );
        }

        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
        });

        var channelsListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
        channelsListRequest.Mine = true;

        // Retrieve the contentDetails part of the channel resource for the authenticated user's channel.
        var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

   ...
```

Comment: How do you call `async Task Run()`?

Comment: I use Run().Wait();

Comment: Ah. I just changed to Run() and it works. Thank you!!

Comment: You should do `await Run();`, is it called in an event handler?

Comment: @Ana: For more information: [don't block on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).